# Changing order in Coordinate field in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, coordinates, latitude-longitude, xy, order

Can I change the order of how my coordinates will display on QGIS?

[image]

I would like to display Latitude, longitude instead of longitude, Latitude

Comment: There is an old script to configure it but it is from old QGIS versions https://github.com/ActiveState/code/tree/73b09edc1b9850c557a79296655f140ce5e853db/recipes/Python/578692_QGstartscript_Change_display

Comment: The `Lat Lon Tool` plugin might be useful. While it won't change the display, it let you copy the XY coordinate as either lat/long or long/lat (and much more)